# Unity animations in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, animation, unity-game-engine

I'm an iOS developer and I'm trying to make 2d animations with Unity 4.3 + RageTools Pro + RageSpline. I want to integrate the animations into a native iOS application .
In Unity I have different kind of animations, different characters, and I want to control these separately in Xcode.

I know how to build unity project to Xcode and I know how to costumize the unity view in Xcode, my problem is that I can't access individually the animations, I can't loop them and I can't switch them in a specific view.
My another problem is that the builded Xcode project from Unity is too large(more than 300 MB).

So the question is if I continue to develop the character animation within unity is it possible to handle separately the animations in Xcode ? or I have to find a another solution (use another animation tool, or export from unity into some different file format(fbx) ). 
In summary I want to make a simple iOS app with simple animations and i'm looking for the simplest solution.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why are you using Unity in the first place? There are many 2D animation tools that can export to more native XCode/iOS frameworks.

Comment: Eventually, I found another solution to my problems...now I use cocos2d-x instead of unity. Anyway, thanks for your response.